# Eigenvalues of a Matrix Power over Arbitrary Fields

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a square matrix over some field $\Bbb{F}$. It can be shown that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $\lambda^n$ is an eigenvalue of $A^n$. In my  linear algebra class we were asked if all eigenvalues of $A^n$ can be written in this form.

In general, the answer is that they cannot. For example, if $\Bbb{F} = \Bbb{R}$ then the matrix 
$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & -1 \\
    1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
has no eigenvalues but $A^2$ has $-1$ as an eigenvalue. In fact, this argument can be generalized to show that if $\Bbb{F}$ is not closed under $n$th roots then the result does not hold over that field.

However, if $\Bbb{F}$ is algebraically closed and $A$ is as above, then it can actually be shown that all eigenvalues of $A^n$ are of the form $\lambda^n$ for some eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$.

Unfortunately, there are fields which are not algebraically closed but which are closed under $n$th roots. Because of this, I wanted to ask the following question:

**For which fields $\Bbb{F}$ does it hold that if $A$ is a square matrix over $\Bbb{F}$ then all eigenvalues of $A^n$ are of the form $\lambda^n$ for some eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$?**

Comment: Does "closed under $n$th roots" mean "every element has at least one $n$th root" or "every element has a full set of $n$th roots"? Because the latter is enough, but the former is not.

Comment: @darij grinberg To be more specific about my claim, if there is any polynomial of the form $x^n - a$ over $\Bbb{F}$ that has no roots then the result does not hold. I don't know about whether or not it holds if $x^n-a$ has at least $1$ but fewer than $n$ roots (and that would in retrospect perhaps be a better definition of closed under $n$th roots)

Comment: E.g., if your field is the reals, and the eigenvalues of $A$ are the nonreal cube roots of 2, then $A^3$ has eigenvalue $2$ which is not $\lambda^3$ for some (real) eigenvalue of of $A$.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson so that clearly implies that "each element has a single $n$th root" is not sufficient and I imagine that it shouldn't be hard to generalize this to show that it is necessary that each element has a full set of $n$th roots. However, it is still not immediately clear to me why this condition should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F$ be a field that contains all the $n$th roots of each of its elements. Let $A$ be a square matrix with entries in $F$. Let $\mu$ be an eigenvalue of $A^n$ with corresponding eigenvector $v\ne0$, so $(A^n-\mu I)v=0$. Then we have $$(A-\lambda_1I)(A-\lambda_2I)\cdots(A-\lambda_nI)v=0$$ where, for each $i$, $\lambda_i^n=\mu$. By hypothesis, each $\lambda_i$ is in $F$. Then there exists $j$ such that $$(A-\lambda_jI)(A-\lambda_{j+1}I)\cdots(A-\lambda_n)v=0,\quad(A-\lambda_{j+1}I)\cdots(A-\lambda_nI)v\ne0$$ Then $(A-\lambda_jI)w=0$, where $$w=(A-\lambda_{j+1}I)\cdots(A-\lambda_nI)v\ne0$$ so $\lambda_j$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. That is, $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda=\lambda_j$ such that $\lambda^n=\mu$.